# How do I initialize a pointer in a struct to null in C++11?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

Here's my struct:

```
struct node {
    int load;
    int tolerance;
    bool has_fired;
    node *in[1];
    node *out[1];
    };
```

I've tried:

```
node mynode;

mynode->in = null;
mynode->in = nullptr;
mynode->in = &nullptr;
mynode->in = 0;
mynode->in = false;
```

I really don't know what's wrong, I remember the first assignment USED to work but not anymore apparently. Any help?

EDIT: In the actual source file 'mynode' is a pointer inside of another struct.

Comment: In your code, 'in' is a array of only 1 element, the array is of type pointer to node. You can't initialize an array to null.

Comment: What's the point in having an array of only one element?

Comment: I wonder why do you make up an array of one element? Is there any special reason or need?

Comment: The one element array is a placeholder, I don't know at this point how many elements will be in the final result.

Comment: @fatalkeystroke that will not work at run time.

Comment: After thinking about the single item array for a while and my intention to grow it I've decided to change the lines to std::vector<node> *in[1];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this perhaps:

```
struct node
{
    int load;
    int tolerance;
    bool has_fired;
    node *in[1] = { nullptr };
    node *out[1] = { nullptr };
};
```

(Note that `node::in` and `node::out` are *arrays* of *pointers*.)

Usage:

```
node n;    // n.in and n.out are initialized
```

In C++11 the brace-or-equal-initializer makes the class a non-aggregate. If that's a problem, you can also omit the initializer and say:

```
node n;
n.in[0] = nullptr;
n.out[0] = nullptr;
```

Or even:

```
node n { 0, 0, false,  { nullptr }, { nullptr } };
```

Answer (score 4):

Try value initialization:

```
node mynode{};
```

This will *value-initialize* all the members, which for built-ins and PODS means zero initializaiton.

Comment: Definitely a fine answer. I suppose the difference is whether the OP wants to initialize a specific object, or provide initialization semantics for the entire class. Good to have a choice of options.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor?

```
struct node
{
    node()
        : in{{ nullptr }}, out{{ nullptr }}
    {}

    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assignment rather than initialization. Since `in` is an array of pointers you have to set the array element to null. Also `mynode` is not a pointer, so you don't use the arrow operator.

```
mynode.in[0] = nullptr;
```