# How do I set a whole struct to null?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, null, initialization

```
struct zaidejas {
    int numeris;
    int aiksteleje;
    bool penketas;
};
int main(){
    zaidejas z[12];
    z = {};
}
```

I get an error in the line of z = {}:

```
error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
```

I have no idea how to fix the error. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a pointer in a struct to null in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596780/how-do-i-initialize-a-pointer-in-a-struct-to-null-in-c11)

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign to an array, only initialize it when you define it, or copy to it once it have been defined.

I recommend initialization:

```
zaidejas z[12] = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can initialize the array as follows:

```
 zaidejas z[12]{};
```

If you want to initialize a single element of your array, you can use:

```
z[0] = zaidejas{};
```

This is the aggregate equivalent of the (constructor-based) initialization that was available in earlier versions of C++

```
z[0] = zaidejas();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just write

```
 zaidejas z[12] = {};
 //             ^^^^
```

This will value-initialize all the array elements, which in turn will zero-initialize each element's class data members.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I set a whole struct to null?

Like this:

```
zaidejas z = {};
```

For your array, you should do:

```
zaidejas z[12] = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 12 elements. If you want to set all of them to null, do something like this

```
int main(){
    int number_elements = 12;
    zaidejas z[number_elements ];
    for (int i = 0; i < number_elements ; z++) z[i] = {}
}
```